# How to insert data into HBase through StarGate REST API

Tags: hadoop, hbase, stargate

According to the StarGate documentation, this is how a CURL command should look like:

```
% curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data '[...]' http://localhost:8000/test/testrow/test:testcolumn
```

This is what I'm trying:

```
% curl -X POST -H "Accept: text/xml" --data '[<CellSet><Row key="cm93MQ=="><Cell column="dGl0bGU6YQ==">d29ya2Vk</Cell></Row></CellSet>]' http://localhost:8080/test/row1/title
```

Keep getting HTTP 415, Unsupported Media Type.. any ideas what I'm missing there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current curl options specify you'd like XML output, and curl is assuming you are posting url-encoded form data (and specifying the wrong Content-Type in the HTTP headers).

Amend your `-H "Accept: text/xml"` to `-H "Content-Type: text/xml"` and you should be good

Comment: Well, got a different type of error now, maybe its getting closer: Error 400 Bad Request

Comment: Should the [] square brackets be around the XML? Does the table 'test' exist?

Comment: Got it, was the [] brackets!! Thanks much!